# Is there an easier way to solve a "Find the locus" problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, locus

**Note:** I am not concerned with the accuracy of my solution so you don't need to redo any of my calculations.

**Original question:** Suppose $ABC$ is an equilateral triangular lamina of side length unity,
resting in two-dimensions. If $A$ and $B$ were constrained to move on the $x$-
and $y$-axis respectively, then what is the locus of the centre of the
triangle?

**My solution:** Let the vertices of $\Delta ABC$ be $A=(x_0,0)$, $B=(0,y_0)$ and
$C=(x,y)$. Let the centre of the triangle be $D=(X,Y)$. We wish to find
the locus of $D$ under the constraints:
\begin{align}
 x_0^2 + y_0^2 &= 0\\
 (x-x_0)^2 + y^2 &= 0\\
 x^2 + (y-y_0)^2 &= 0
\end{align}
Since $D$ is the centre of the triangle, we know
    $$X = \frac{x+x_0}{3}\quad\text{and}\quad Y = \frac{y+y_0}{3}$$

**Parametrizing:**
Let $\theta$ be the angle that the edge $AB$ makes with the $x$-axis.
We use (\theta) as our parameter of choice to write,
\begin{align*}
    x_0 &= \cos\theta\\
    y_0 &= \sin\theta
\end{align*}
for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

This implies,
$$(x-\cos\theta)^2 + y^2 = 0$$
We can parametrize this with another parameter $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$ as
\begin{align*}
 x &= \cos\theta + \cos\phi\\
 y &= \sin\phi
\end{align*}
Plugging these back into third equation gives
$$(\cos\theta+\cos\phi)^2+(\sin\phi-\sin\theta)^2 = 1$$
After lots of algebraic manipulations...
\begin{align*}
 X  &= \frac{1}{2}\cos\theta\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\sin\theta & Y &= \frac{1}{2}\sin\theta\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\cos\theta\\
\end{align*}

**Deparametrizing:**
To obtain equation for the locus of $D$, we eliminate the parameter. Solving
for $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$, we get
    $$\cos\theta = 3X\mp\sqrt{3}Y \quad\text{and}\quad
  \sin\theta = 3Y\mp\sqrt{3}X$$
Therefore, $X$ and $Y$ satisfy
    $$(3X\mp\sqrt{3}Y)^2+(3Y\mp\sqrt{3}X)^2=1$$
i.e.,
    $$12X^2+12Y^2\mp12\sqrt{3}XY=1$$
These are two oblique ellipses.

**My actual questions:**

1. Is there an easier way to solve the question i.e. was there no need to parametrize, seeing as I am deparametrizing anyway?
2. Even before doing any of the calculations, is there some result/theorem that guarantees that a relationship among $X, Y$ and $Z$ exists. (Subquestion: is it possible that making the problem more complicated by say looking at equilateral tetrahedrons in 3D or something might not even be solvable?)

**Note:** I am not concerned with the accuracy of my solution so you don't need to redo any of my calculations.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to embed the construction in the complex plane and set
$$ A=\sin\theta,\qquad B=i\cos\theta $$
to have
$$ C = (A-B)e^{\pm i\pi/3}+B = e^{-i\theta\pm i\pi/3}+B$$
so that:
$$ 3D = A+B+C = e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta\pm i\pi/3}+i\cos\theta. $$
That leads to the same equations for the ellipses.
If three vertices of a tetrahedron lie on the $x-,y-$ and $z-$ axis we may assume they are $A(a,0,0),B(0,b,0),C(0,0,c)$ and $a^2+b^2=a^2+c^2=b^2+c^2$ must hold, so $|a|=|b|=|c|$ and there are just $16$ possible locations for $D$ and the centroid $G$ of $ABCD$.

Comment: Thanks @jack. That definitely answers my first question above. Do you have some more ideas for question 2? To paraphrase: is there any any theorem/result that guarantees when such a system of quadratic equations is "solvable" to obtain a single equation for the locus?

Comment: Also, complex numbers wouldn't work for the 3D problem, right? I was hoping for solution that would work regardless of the dimension I am dealing with. (I see now that the tetrahedron generalization is perhaps not the correct generalization.)

Comment: @vkarve: obviously complex numbers do not work in $3D$, and there isn't a single equation for the locus: even in the $2D$ case, you get $2$ ellipses, corresponding to a quartic equation with two quadratic factors.